# Accent issues in office 2007 and internet explorer

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, internet-explorer-9, language

We were brought a laptop with **Windows 7 Home Premium** setup for Greek language speakers.
The installed  languages and keyboards are: English (US), as default, and Greek.

There is also installed Microsoft Office 2007 Greek and Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 Greek.

When the user tries to write accented letters such as "ό, Ά" in office or IE, instead of the correct letter the result is: **`α** and not **ά**

Do you need any other information on the system or what are the suggestions to search for the cause of this problem?

Comment: Does the described behaviour happen with the English (US) keyboard, with the Greek one, or both?

Comment: With the greek keyboard only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was some kind of malware software that was causing this.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why would you have malware on a new laptop? What malware was it (to help others with the same problem). In any case +1 for finding it, πατριώτη :)

Comment: It wasn't a new laptop. The malware was delivered through e-mail. I can't remember its name, but the e-mail was about paypal (fake of course).